# Multiple Arguments in Google Sheets for SUMIF

Tags: google-sheets, multiple-arguments

I am trying to create a formula to capture expenditures from a year-long entry sheet into separate sheets by month.  Can you help?

This isn't working:

```
=IF(('ENTER Transactions HERE'!B$5:B,">="&DATE(2024,1,1),"<="&DATE(2024,1,31)), sumif('ENTER Transactions HERE'!$E:$E,$B28,'ENTER Transactions HERE'!$C:$C))
```

I tried sumif at the beginning instead of if. I have researched several sites and have viewed some videos, trying to be incredibly careful with each character.  I am at a loss.  Thanks in advance for any support-- I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can adjust your formula:

```
=SUMIFS('ENTER Transactions HERE'!$C:$C, 'ENTER Transactions HERE'!$B:$B, ">="&DATE(2024,1,1), 'ENTER Transactions HERE'!$B:$B, "<="&DATE(2024,1,31), 'ENTER Transactions HERE'!$E:$E, $B28)
```

- `'ENTER Transactions HERE'!$C:$C`: This is the range you want to sum.
- `'ENTER Transactions HERE'!$B:$B, ">="&DATE(2024,1,1)` and `'ENTER Transactions HERE'!$B:$B, "<="&DATE(2024,1,31)`: These are your date criteria, ensuring that only transactions between January 1, 2024, and January 31, 2024, are included.
- `'ENTER Transactions HERE'!$E:$E, $B28`: This is your additional criterion (if you have one, like a specific category or type of transaction).

Comment: You did it, Iman.  It works!!!! :)  Thank you so much.